# Form-encoded POST in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Currently, I am sending request to a API using POST.Following is the code:

```
byte[] response = client.UploadValues("http://myapi.com/2.2/mymethod ", 
                                      "POST", new NameValueCollection()
                  {
                     { "parameter1", "value1"},
                     { "parameter2" ,"value2"}
                  });
```

But,the API expects Form-encoded POST.How I can fire a Form-encoded POST using ASP.NET? Am I required to develop an HTML form interface and the parameter values are required to be passed through the control's of the Form?

Comment: your request type should be form encoded  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: your client variable should allow you to set content type , set that with above and ur'done